# django: django 1.2 on ubuntu lucid

Tags: django, django-1.2, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to run django on my ubuntu lucid, but I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 66, in activate
    return real_activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 55, in _curried
    return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 36, in delayed_loader
    return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 193, in activate
    _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 176, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/gruszczy/Programy/bozorth/../bozorth/notifications/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have created and empty project and only changed database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'test.db3',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Am I lacking some dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define databases in [Multiple database format](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: I wrote:

`DATABASES = {
 'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
  'NAME': 'bozorth.db3'
 }
}`

but the error is the same.

Comment: Hmmm...Maybe you need to try recreate your project, and then add your apps to new one.

P.S. Are you remove old version of django before installing 1.2.1 ?

Comment: No way, I can't recreate the project, it's too old and too big now ;-)

Comment: I have done apt-get remove python-django before, so I believe it's ok.

Comment: It seems, that django doesn't work even on an empty project. I have changed the question to reflect this. Any idea, what now might be wrong?

Comment: Ok, it seems, that some old eggs must have been messing with my projects.

Comment: Can you try 1st change "django.db.backends.sqlite3" to "sqlite3"...
If not help, can you try for example use mysql or other databases?

P.S error appears on "validate" or when you try to "runserver"?